# Send attachment file in outgoing mail body in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email-attachments

I am trying to send S3 url file in mail body, but I am getting error

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen
```

I want something like this, but I am unable to achieve this one

[image]

```
@path = s3_url
attachments["output.pdf"] = {
  mime_type: "application/pdf",
  content: HTTParty.get(@path).response.try(:body)
}
mail(to: 'xyz@gmail.com', subject: "Test Attchment", body: File.read(URI.parse(@path)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the PDF using Net::HTTP or HTTPary and read the response to set the attachment in the mailer.

Try it this way:

```
# change the file name if required
mail.attachments["output.pdf"] = {
  mime_type: "application/pdf",
  content: HTTParty.get(s3_path).response.try(:body)
}
```

Comment: mail is method in ApplicationMailer, then how can I use this mail.attachments

Comment: Please checkout the usage in the [rubydoc documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionMailer/Base) or [apidock documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionMailer/Base/attachments) it would help you to understand the use of attachments better.

Comment: I already implement the code that is mentioned in documentation for attachment but it show in header. I am trying to add in body. I am trying to understand your code how can i user mails.attachments.

Comment: Like the `mail` method, `attachments` is also a method provided by the ActionMailer::Base.

Comment: I have update the code and I am getting this erro, "TypeError: no implicit conversion of URI::HTTPS into String"

Comment: Possible for you to upload a test pdf and provide the link so that I can check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251961/discussion-between-kunalk-and-smith).